# Distinct values despite a column in a case expression creating non distinct values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by

I want to get one line per APP_ID but I am selecting Operating_System in a case statement which means 3 rows are returned for the same APP_ID.

```
SELECT DISTINCT [APP_ID], [APP_NAME], [BATCH_ID], [Start_Date], 
       CASE 
         WHEN [Operating_System] LIKE '%Windows%' 
            then COUNT([HOSTNAME])  
         ELSE '' 
       END AS 'Windows',  
       CASE 
         WHEN [server_pam_Operating_System] LIKE '%Linux%' 
           then COUNT([HOSTNAME]) 
         ELSE '' 
       END AS 'Linux' 
FROM [dbo].[table a]
WHERE [APP_ID] = 'APP-99'
GROUP BY [APP_ID], [APP_NAME], [BATCH_ID], [Start_Date]
```

Actual results:

```
APP_ID  APP_NAME BATCH_ID   Start_Date  Windows Linux
APP-99  APS to define   to define   0   49
APP-99  APS to define   to define   3   0
APP-99  APS to define   to define   7   0
```

Expected results:

```
APP_ID  APP_NAME BATCH_ID   Start_Date  Windows Linux
APP-99  APS to define   to define   10  49
```

Comment: The code did not show clearly above so here it is again:

SELECT DISTINCT [APP_ID], [APP_NAME], [BATCH_ID], [Start_Date],
CASE WHEN [Operating_System] LIKE '%Windows%' then COUNT([HOSTNAME])  
ELSE '' END AS 'Windows',

CASE WHEN [server_pam_Operating_System] LIKE '%Linux%' then COUNT([HOSTNAME]) ELSE '' END AS 'Linux'

FROM [dbo].[table a]
  WHERE [APP_ID] = 'APP-99'
  GROUP BY [APP_ID], [APP_NAME], [BATCH_ID], [Start_Date]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no need distinct and use aggregation before case

```
    SELECT  [APP_ID], [APP_NAME], [BATCH_ID], [Start_Date],         
    sum(CASE WHEN [Operating_System] LIKE '%Windows%' then 1  
    ELSE 0 END) AS Windows,
    sum(CASE WHEN [server_pam_Operating_System] LIKE '%Linux%' 
    then 1 ELSE 0) END AS Linux    
      FROM [dbo].[table a]
      WHERE [APP_ID] = 'APP-99'
      GROUP BY [APP_ID], [APP_NAME], [BATCH_ID], [Start_Date]
```